# JQuery append checkboxes to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using dropzoe.js form and I append a lot of input values to the form with jquery. I have text fields, select fields, and checkboxes. I used to append the inputs to the form with a foreach loop but it doesn't work with checkboxes. How can I append them aswell?
Some checkbox examples (it comes from a php select, so the name is always looks like this:

```
name="technical[<?php echo $id ?>]"
```

and the id aswell:

```
id="technical-<?php echo $id ?>"
```

```
<div class="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="technical[3]" id="technical-3" value="1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="technical-3">Something</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="technical[4]" id="technical-4" value="1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="technical-4">Something else</label>
</div>
```

The append part of the JQuery script looks like this:

```
this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
    $(":input[name]", $("form")).each(function() {
        formData.append(this.name, $(':input[name=' + this.name + ']', $("form")).val());
    });
});
```

but it says the following:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :input[name=technical[3]]
```

Comment: Yes, it's the name attribute of the inputs. The ```:``` sign didn't cause any errors tho.

Comment: I wanted to add checkboxes to my form, but I need their names to be arrays, like 'name=example[]' because I have multiple checkboxes. But my each loop throws the error I pasted above because of the array.

Comment: It appends the value of the inputs.

Comment: You might just need to wrap your [attr] selector in quotes: `':input[name="' + this.name + '"]'`